# Alternative software for processing Molden files?

Tags: computational-chemistry

I am trying to salvage old data, and one of my output files is in Molden format.

1. I tried downloading Molden [at its homesite](http://www.cmbi.ru.nl/molden/howtoget.html) but the link does not seem to work.
2. Is there another way to access Molden format files?

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is probably off-topic - rather informatics than chemistry.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/33932/4945  I had no problems downloading molden from the linked homepage.  try this: ftp://ftp.cmbi.ru.nl/pub/molgraph/molden/molden5.7.tar.gz

Comment: @Mithoron no one in informatics will have an answer to this besides computational chemists there. This is the best SE to get an answer to such a question.

Comment: @Mithoron In principle questions of this type are the reason for my newest meta discussion: [What's our (maybe updated) take on questions about (quantum) chemical software?](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3425/4945).

Comment: Maybe avogadro, or VMD (Visual Molecular Dynamics)

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly sure Molden can be downloaded. However, programs like JMol, and Chemcraft are usually cross-compatiblr with molden.

Comment: As far as I know, ChemCraft is not able to read molden files. I don't use JMol, so maybe that works. It would be best if you could support your claims with more data, and/ or links to documentation of the programs.

Comment: Even though ChemCraft does not open `.molden` files, it is able to open `.wfn` files.
So if using ChemCraft (or any other `.wfn`-compatible software that can't read `.molden` files) is imperative, my [answer](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/66734/40029) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're OK with converting, [Molden2AIM](https://github.com/zorkzou/Molden2AIM) may be a good alternative.
It is able to convert `.molden` files into `.wfn` files which are easier to handle in my opinion (the software actually does a bit more than just that, such as generating `.47` files for NBO analysis).

If your `.molden` files were generated by [ORCA](https://orcaforum.cec.mpg.de/), you may also try an [automated script](https://github.com/chemical-scripts/wavefunk) that handles the details of using Molden2AIM for you.